# Retractable reel for twine - does it exist?

Tags: gear, ropes

I occasionally use a very long stretch of twine to transport light gear (<1lb) between my partner and I when we're camping out ~30m from each other.

Unreeling and reeling this twine is extremely cumbersome - it's often tangled and I have to buy a new batch.

What would be handy is a cheap, retractable reel that I can use to unload and reload (think vacuum cleaner cord).  Does anything small, cheap, automated (press a button to retract), and portable exist for extremely thin twine (not electrical cord)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A wreck reel sold for scuba divers might give you what you want. They vary from simple line holders up through heavy duty reels.

Comment: Thank you Nik.  I just did some searching - I see manually operated reels for <$30 but I'm looking for a motorized or spring-loaded mechanism so I can just press a button and have the line reeled in that price range.

Comment: @user666 No spring would let you coil up 100' of line (safely) and a button would mean you need batteries for a trivial task, one that could be done faster manually and more reliably. THIS is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The thing that immediately jumps to mind for this is a [retractable washing line](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Metaltex-Double-Outdoor-Retractable-Washing/dp/B00J8I1GWQ), which should have enough length for what you want. However, they are relatively heavy and aren't exactly thin twine.

Another option may be a [automatic fishing real](http://www.omegasurvivalsupply.com/products/mechanical-auto-fishing-fish-reel-spring-loaded). However, its probably not long enough for what you want.

Comment: My immediate thought was a retractable washing line too. I think if the OP was willing to modify one then this would be a workable solution.